# How do the ridge or lasso coefficient changes when we add more variables

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, lasso, ridge-regression

Suppose we run ridge or lasso regression over a bunch of features. And now suppose we add one more feature into the regressions. What will happen to the coefficients of the "old" features?

I think generally that depends on how correlated the new feature is with the existing feature. But by simply looking at the ridge or lasso objective function, it seems to be a bit hard for me to think about this question. Or I am looking more for an intuitive explanation. I am also very curious about how ridge shrinks and lasso shrinks/selects coefficients in general. For example, which coefficient to shrink more etc.